# $V \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. Does $\lVert I_n - V \rVert_\infty \leq \epsilon$ imply lower bounds on the smallest eigenvalue of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, upper-lower-bounds, matrix-norms

Let $V \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Suppose $\lVert I_n - V \rVert_\infty \leq \epsilon$, where the norm is the operator norm.

I would like to get a tight lower bound on $\lambda_{\mathrm{min}}$, the smallest eigenvalue of $V$. Intuitively, it seems the smallest eigenvalue should be at least $1 - \epsilon$, but I'm not sure how one would show that. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Is $V$ positive definite? Or how are you defining smallest eigenvalue?

Comment: If $||I_n-V|| \le \epsilon$ for any operator norm, then the spectrum of $C$ is included in the closed disk $\overline{D}(1,\epsilon)$. To see this, look at $||(I_n-V)x||$ when $x$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Do you mean "the spectrum of $V$"? If so, I think that's what I'm looking for...that all the eigenvalues are within $\pm \epsilon$ of $1$ (since $V$ is "close" to the identity).

Comment: The spectral radius of $I_n-V$ is $\leq$ it's operator norm, and $\sigma(I_n-V)=1-\sigma(V)$.

Comment: @Ruy I'm sorry, I don't follow. Is there a typo in your comment? Do you mind providing slightly more detail (and explaining your notation)? Thank you for the help.

Comment: By $\sigma(V)$ I mean the spectrum of $V$. Do you know what is the spectral radius?  How about the spectral mapping theorem?

Comment: Ok, now I see, thanks.

Comment: Glad to  be able to help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda$ be any eigenvalue of $V$.  Say $Vx = \lambda x$ where $x$ is a nonzero vector.  We may assume $\|x\| = 1$.  Then
$$
(I-V)x = x-\lambda x = (1-\lambda) x
$$
so
$$
|1-\lambda| = |1-\lambda|\;\|x\| = \|(1-\lambda)x\| = \|(I-V)x\|
\le \|I-V\|_\infty\;\|x\| = \|I-V\|_\infty \le \epsilon .
$$
Every eigenvalue of $V$ lies in the disk
$\{\lambda \in \mathbb C \mid |1-\lambda| \le \epsilon\}$ .  I guess that whatever "smallest eigenvalue of $V$" means, it would at least be an eigenvalue of $V$.